# How to display the output of a Linux command on stdout and also pipe it to another command?

Tags: linux, shell, command, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pipe stdout while keeping it on screen ? (and not to a output file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file)

For example I want to run the command:

```
ls -l
```

Then I have the output to stdout:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 12 12:34 Desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1234 Apr 12 00:00 file
```

And I want to redirect this output to another command for some further processing (like redirecting to 'head -1' to extract first line). Can I do it in just one line?

Comment: `tee` will do what you want.  Also, this question is better suited for http://superuser.com

Comment: @icyrock.com The first method (`tee` the output to `tty`) works for me. But the second method (using process substitution) doesn't. Anyway problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tee will work. Something like:

```
ls -l | tee | head -1
```

To append the output to a file:

```
ls -l | tee -a output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but then the output of `ls -l` doesn't appear on the console. What I want is both the output of `ls -l` and `ls -l | head -1`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [`tpipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tpipe) which allows you to pipe a command to two other commands (like a fork), but it's not installed by default on most machines. Using it, your problem would be solved by:

```
ls -l | tpipe head -1
```