# How to show command output in stdout and also transfer it to pipe

Tags: bash

Lets say I have the fallowing cmd:

```
ls | grep dir
```

If there are folders which names contains `dir` then ill see them. 
If there arent, then I wont see any output at all.

Now, What i want is to see the output of the `ls` command, and then also see the final output after the `grep`.

Lets say something like this:

```
>>ls | grep dir
filea fileb filec
filed dir1  dir2

dir1 
dir2
```

Where the first 2 rows are the result of `ls` and the last 2 rows are the result of the `grep` command.

How do i do that?

Comment: Check this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file>

    ls |tee /dev/tty |grep Public

you can use tty command to find terminal and replace it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls |tee /dev/tty |grep dir
```

will do that, although it won't put a space between the two parts.

Comment: Works as a charm :) THX

Answer (score 0):

I'm cheating a bit there, but can't you just do both commands one after another?
like (adding an echo to put some space between them):

```
 ls && echo && ls | grep dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to run ls twice:

```
ls; ls -1 | grep dir
```

Please pay attention -1 option. grep is line oriented that's why ls should print one dir entry per line.

Comment: `-1` is only necessary if the output is a terminal; when writing to a pipe or file, `-1` is effectively implied.