# Display output from last command in bash until loop

Tags: bash

```
until commandThatProducesOutput | grep -m 1 "Done"
do
        ???
        sleep 5
done
```

While this script is running, I'd like to pipe the output that commandThatProducesOutput produces to the screen but can't seem to get the correct syntax.

Comment: [xy-problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Seems like `command ... | tee /dev/tty | grep ...` should do what you want.  See [how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
output=$(commandThatProducesOutput)

until echo "$output" | grep -m 1 "Done"
do
    echo "$output"
    output=$(commandThatProducesOutput)
done
```

Comment: `echo "$output"`, please.