# Filter stdout using sed, write filtered output into file but keep unfiltered output on stdout (screen)

Tags: bash, unix, sed, stdout

I would like to write some filtered output of a given command (`rsync`) into a file but keep the complete unfiltered output on stdout (the screen/terminal).

I've tried some combinations of `sed`, `tee` & `process substitution` but cannot make this work.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
rsync -aAXz --stats -v src dest > >(sed '0,/^$/d' | tee -a "summary.log")
```

`sed '0,/^$/d'` deletes everything before the first blank line which leaves `rsync`'s summary and deletes the leading verbose output. This is working as expected and only prints the summary to `summary.log`.

Obviously it also deletes the verbose output from `stdout` since the `tee` command only receives the filtered `sed` output over the pipe.

How can I write to `stdout` before filtering with `sed` to see all the verbose output on the screen/terminal?

Comment: Could you explain this with an example?

Comment: Here's another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file?rq=1

Comment: `rysnc | tee >(sed 'do stuff' >outputfile)`

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To write your complete output from `stdout` to the log file, do that first (using `tee`), and then deal with the terminal. Something like this:

```
rsync -aAXz --stats -v src dest | tee -a "summary.log" | sed '0,/^$/d'
```

That "splits" or duplicates the output stream, with one copy of the complete stream being diverted by `tee` to the output log, and another copy being sent to its `stdout`, which becomes the input to `sed`....