# lp is not working in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a test script that contains the following:

```
lp -d HP ~/cap/alpha/error
```

HP is a designated printer on my wireless network and ~/cap/alpha/error is the full file path to the file containing the report from a python unit test.

The command works from the terminal window but not from the script called test.

I can't figure out why this is not working?

Comment: Are you using `lp` with its full path from inside the script or just `lp`?

Comment: Replace `~` with `/home/$USER`

Comment: there is a standard unix command named `test`. Get in the habit of making your test scripts with names like `myTest`, or `testR` to eliminate a whole class of debugging problems. ALSO, please be more specific about "does not work". Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

[How to pipe stdout while keeping it on screen ? (and not to a output file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file#5677265) (answer by jilliagre):

```
echo 'ee' | tee /dev/tty | foo
```

This answer worked for me as follows:

```
$ python3 "mytest.py" | tee /dev/tty/ | lp -d brother
```

printing to both my terminal and my printer.

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted.