# Build and run Dockerfile with one command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Is it possible to build image from Dockerfile and run it with a single command?**
There is one command `docker build` to build a Dockerfile and `docker run -it` to run the image.

Is there any combination of these two commands to make it easier to build and run with just one command?

Comment: If you elaborate on your use-case, there may be better options we can present.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My use case is to quickly iterate when I am editing a Dockerfile I am working on.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

No, there is no single command. But if you tag your image as you build it, it will be easier to run:

```
docker build -t foo . && docker run -it foo
```

Comment: Good answer because you can then easily remove the image if you'd like: `docker rmi foo`.

Answer (score 604):

If you want to avoid tagging, `docker build -q` outputs nothing but the **final image hash**, which you can use as the argument to `docker run`:

```
docker run -it $(docker build -q .)
```

And add `--rm` to `docker run` if you want the container removed automatically when it exits.

```
docker run --rm -it $(docker build -q .)
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, since it doesn't clutter the local image repository

Comment: @InsOp Actually, this produces local images, too. They're just not tagged.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't show you the regular build output from `docker build` :/

Comment: @Lion that the point of `-q` option. To make it quiet, to output only the autogenerated tag. And that's it. Feel free to transform that stdin as you like.

Comment: To get the output of the build, you should adapt the [answer of 
Viacheslav Shalamov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220656/3207406) : `docker build . | tee /dev/tty | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -I{} docker run --rm {}`

Comment: This answer is a nice technique! I use it for a while, but then realize it is undesirable whenever I'd need to append a run-time command at the end, such as `docker run ... $(docker build -q .) python foo.py`. The problem is, if the "docker build ..." part accidentally run into error, it turns out the "docker run ..." part would effectively ignore the build error, and proceed and treat the next word (in this case, the "python") as if it were a image name. In other words, it now attempts to run `foo.py` with an image named `python`. That is not what you would want.

Comment: For people that have problems with specifying a Dockerfile that is in another folder, here you have an example of how you can do it: docker run --rm -it $(docker build -q -f testFolder/Dockerfile .)

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `Error: /usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header`

Comment: @RayLuo: Fix: `docker run ... $(docker build -q . || echo build_broken) python foo.py`. Obviously won't fix the underlying error, but it avoids using `python` as an image name.

Comment: I dont need that `-it` to run ^^

Answer (score 85):

I use docker-compose for this convenience since most of the apps I'm building are talking to external services sooner or later, so if I'm going to use it anyway, why not use it from the start. Just have docker-compose.yml as:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

and then just run the app with:

```sh
docker-compose up --build app
```

It will rebuild the image or reuse the container depending on whether there were changes made to the image definition.

Answer (score 8):

Recently I started getting a *promo* message about using `docker scan` after every build.

> Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them

Here's what I *used* to do:

```bash
docker build --quiet .
```

and here's what is working now:

```bash
docker build --quiet . | head -n1
```

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/scan-cli-plugin/issues/149#issuecomment-823969364 on how to disable that message permanently.

`export DOCKER_SCAN_SUGGEST=false`

Comment: @bozdoz What does a promo message have to do with building and running in one command?

Comment: @AlxVallejo See above comment.  Docker is printing a line about using Snyk after each build.  So, as per my answer, what I used to do wasn't working anymore (because docker build was no longer printing solely the image hash)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is posted as a separate answer. I was confused just like AlxVallejo especially since this response appears first in the thread.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Makefile, I find this snippet useful:

```
build:
    @docker build . | tee .buildlog

bash: build
    @docker run --rm -it $(shell grep "Successfully built" .buildlog | cut -d ' ' -f 3) /bin/bash
```

You don't need tagging, like in @jonathon-reinhart answer, but you also get the build output.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do `docker build` and pipe image name which it outputs to `docker run`:

```
docker build . | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs -I{} docker run {}
```

- `docker build` will give you multi-line text `... Successfully built 18e77bc0d83a`
- you get the last line with `tail -n1`
- split by `' '` and get `3`rd word with `cut -d' ' -f3`
- pass it as argument to `run` with `xargs -I{} docker run {}`

Comment: add [`| tee /dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677265/3207406) after `docker build .` to get the full output!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a reusable solution, you could install this docker plugin which i created:
https://github.com/stasmihailov/docker-script

Then you could build and run a Dockerfile as follows:

```
docker script ./Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PC

Make a `run.bat` file. Then in the file add this:

```
docker build -t foo . 
docker run -it foo
```

To run the file using powershell or cmd do this:

```
./run.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

### `docker-build-and-run`

I've created a little helper command for building and running, in a single command. On Linux or Mac, you can add this to your `~/.bash_profile` to make it available in the Terminal.

#### Usage:

```sh
docker-build-and-run BUILD_ARGS [-- RUN_ARGS] [-- RUN_COMMAND]
```

#### Examples:

```sh
docker-build-and-run . -- npm run test
docker-build-and-run --file ./Dockerfile . -- -v ~/volume:/var/volume -- node server.js
```

#### The Script:

Add this to a `.sh` file, or add it to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```sh
TERM_GREEN="\033[1;32m"
TERM_BLUE="\033[1;34m"
TERM_NC="\033[0m"
docker-build-and-run() {
    if [[ -z "$@" ]]; then
        echo "
            Usage:
                docker-build-and-run BUILD_ARGS [-- RUN_ARGS] [-- RUN_COMMAND]
            Examples:
                docker-build-and-run . -- npm run test
                docker-build-and-run --file ./Dockerfile . -- -v ~/volume:/var/volume -- node server.js
        "
        return
    fi

    # Extract the segments between the dashes:
    BEFORE_THE_DASHES=
    while (( "$#" )); do
        if [[ "$1" = "--" ]]; then
            shift
            break
        fi
        BEFORE_THE_DASHES="$BEFORE_THE_DASHES $1"
        shift
    done
    SEGMENT_1=$BEFORE_THE_DASHES

    BEFORE_THE_DASHES=
    while (( "$#" )); do
        if [[ "$1" = "--" ]]; then
            shift
            break
        fi
        BEFORE_THE_DASHES="$BEFORE_THE_DASHES $1"
        shift
    done
    SEGMENT_2=$BEFORE_THE_DASHES

    SEGMENT_3=$@


    BUILD_ARGS=$SEGMENT_1
    RUN_ARGS=$SEGMENT_2
    RUN_COMMAND=$SEGMENT_3
    if [ -z "$RUN_COMMAND" ]; then
      RUN_COMMAND=$RUN_ARGS
      RUN_ARGS=
    fi


    TEMP_TAG=docker-build-and-run-temp

    docker rm -f $TEMP_TAG 2>/dev/null
    printf "${TERM_GREEN}Building Docker container (${TERM_BLUE}docker build $BUILD_ARGS${TERM_GREEN})${TERM_NC}\n" \
    && docker build --tag $TEMP_TAG $BUILD_ARGS \
    && printf "${TERM_GREEN}Running Docker container (${TERM_BLUE}docker run $RUN_ARGS $RUN_COMMAND${TERM_GREEN})${TERM_NC}\n" \
    && docker run --rm -it $RUN_ARGS --label $TEMP_TAG $TEMP_TAG $RUN_COMMAND
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider automatically giving a name to the generated image:

```
alias docker-up=docker build -t $(basename $PWD) . && docker run -it $(basename $PWD)
```