# How to pipe output to stdout and into another process in docker

Tags: linux, shell, docker

I would like to pipe standard output of a program that is running inside a docker container while keeping the output in the docker logs (i.e. stdout).

Another stackoverflow question ([How to pipe stdout while keeping it on screen ? (and not to a output file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677201/how-to-pipe-stdout-while-keeping-it-on-screen-and-not-to-a-output-file)) suggests using `foo | tee /dev/tty | bar`, but this doesn't work when docker is run in non-interactive mode because `/dev/tty` doesn't exist.

Is this possible?

Comment: `foo | tee >(bar)` ?

Comment: This seems to work as long as I use bash instead of sh which is fine. Feel free to change this comment to an answer so I can tick it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to duplicate the stdout of one program called `foo` to output it on your script stdout and pipe it to another program called `bar`. That's exactly what [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) is for.

```
foo | tee >(bar)
```

If you don't have the shell that supports process substitution, you can do the same in a few more lines, by creating a fifo and running `cat $fifo` in background and running `too "$fifo"` to duplicate the stream to stdout and fifo:

```
fifo=$(mktemp -u); mkfifo $fifo;
cat "$fifo" &
foo | tee "$fifo" | bar
```