# Executing shell script from another shell script & Checking for a particular string from the output of invoked shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, cut

Let's take example.
There are 2 scripts,

1. *main.sh*
2. *invoke.sh*

I want to execute *invoke.sh* script from *main.sh*. When the script *invoke.sh* executes from *main.sh*, *invoke.sh* produces below output on Linux terminal,

```
jbhaijy@ubuntu:~$./main.sh

Resources available on this system:
  CPU TYPE: x86_64
  Num cores: 4
  Total RAM: 15979 MB
  Avail RAM: 13299 MB
  Total disk: 343 GB
  Avail disk: 60 GB
  GPU Type: None
  State: unregistered
```

I want to check specific string i.e. **State: registered** or **State: unregistered** from the above(invoke.sh) output & returned **State** to *main.sh*. Based on the State string, *main.sh* will inform the user that device is registered or unregistered.

Questions:

1. How we can check particular State string i.e. "registered" or "unregistered"?
2. How we can returned State string to *main.sh*?

Hope my question gives enough clarity to you.

Comment: Hints: `grep -q pattern`. Its exits status is OK if the pattern occurs. Use it in main.sh to call invoke.sh and check its output like `if ./invoke.sh | grep -q unregistered; then echo "do something here"; else echo "do something else"; fi;`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter-ReinstateMonica. It seems string search is working but I am not getting the invoke.sh script whole output on the console. Pls suggest how can we modify your command to get whole output along with particular string output. Thanks again.

Comment: So you want the entire output visible on the console to the user but *also* take some action?

Comment: I wrote an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine whether a program or script output contains a string you pipe it through `grep`. `grep -q` is normally used for that; it will by design not output anything but only indicate by its exit status whether anything was found:

```
if ./invoke.sh | grep -q unregistered
    then echo "do something for an unregistered machine"
    else echo "do something else for a registered one"
fi
```

If you additionally want the entire output from `invoke.sh` on the screen, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677265/3150802) suggested to `tee` it to /dev/tty. `tee` is a command that "splits" output, like a T-intersection, into two parts: One continues to stdout, the other one is written to a file. (This is often used to save output while at the same time watching it in real time.) Now unfortunately we need the stdout for grep, and we don't want any files; but *nix treats almost everything as a file, including your <strike>teletype</strike> console. The console is the pseudo file `/dev/tty` to which you can let tee write:

```
if ./invoke.sh | tee /dev/tty | grep -q unregistered
    then echo "do something here"
    else echo "do something else"
fi
```

Comment: Hey @Peter, Its working as expected. Thanks for valuable inputs.

Comment: @Yunus Nice that it worked! Btw, the canonical way to express gratitude and satisfaction is upvoting and accepting ;-).